# Retrieve Apple ID in Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova

Maybe someone knows, there are some plugin cordova, allowing to determine the user's Apple ID on iOS? I need to use this account to identify the user in the application, if it is, for example, decides to change the device to another. I would be very grateful for any help for two days looking for on the Internet, can not find anything. Sorry for my english

Comment: Some thing like https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-secureudid

Comment: That solution will work to identify a device but will not work when user changes devices.

Comment: what do you mean? device Id or UDID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*there is no way in iOS SDK to get AppleId (email or password) or any information about it* this type of data is very sensitive and I hope well secured ;) So no plugin for Cordova.

To identify an user in your application you can use other ways, for example Game Center Account or  Facebook login to identify user. I suggest you to find more information about these steps:

- Allow user to sign using game center or facebook for iOS applications
- Store obtained identifier at your server
- Store app/game data at your server with obtained identifier
- When user sign back to your app you can identify him at your server
- You may restore some app/game data from your server after user sign on other device

Depends on your needs what you need to store and restore when user sign back.
Also I suggest read some parts from https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/  like 17.2, 22.7 before you made final decision about what and how you will ask user for some credentials or other private dat.

Answer (score 1):

To identify a user across devices the only real solution is the implement an authentication system of some kind.  There is nothing accessible through the API to uniquely identify the user.

Comment: But on android I was able to do with this plugin: [https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-android-email](https://github.com/ccsoft/cordova-android-email).
I'm sure that can be done on iOS similar to the Apple ID

Comment: There are many things you can access on Android not available on iOS.  Much different operating systems.